# Components and Slots approach

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-component

I have actually 2 global components one for Admin and other one for Modal. The Admin component have a child comp called Page and the Page comp have others childs. I want to pass content directly to Page comp via slots. Like this:

app.js

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { Admin, Modal }
})
```

Admin.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <page>
      <slot></slot>
    </page>
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  components: { Page }
}
```

Page.vue

```
<template>
<div>
   <page-header>
        <slot name="page-header">
            <h1 class="page-title">
                <slot name="page-title">
                    Page Title
                </slot>
            </h1>
        </slot>
    </page-header>
    <page-body>
        <slot>
            Page Body
        </slot>
    </page-body>
    <page-footer>
        <slot name="page-footer">
            Page Footer
        </slot>
    </page-footer>
</div>
</template>

export default {
        components: {
            pageHeader,
            pageBody,
            pageFooter
        }
}
```

index.html

```
<admin>
    <div slot="page-header">
       Header Test
    </div>
    Body Test
    <div slot="page-footer">
      Footer Test
    </div>
</admin>
```

I don't need to use Page as global component, Please any idea?? Hope you understand what I'm looking for...

Thanks

Comment: If you want to pass data from parent to child one option to do it is with props.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think slots are designed to do this. If you need data to be persisted between parent and children then use either props as @Belmin Bedak suggested. When you pass a prop to a component it will be available to all its children. 
If you need to persist state on front-end I strongly recommend using Vuex as source of data for all components ( only use if it becomes more complex to have data scattered across components ).